# With Oracle, how can I use an IN clause with multiple Arrays?

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle

For a while now, I have been using queries like this when I need to select several entities by ID at once and I can't predict how many entities I need to select:

```
select * from MY_ENTITY where ID in (select * table(?))`
```

The parameter is an SQL `ARRAY` of whatever is the relevant type for my entity's ID.

This is a bit ugly, but the query runs much faster that using something like `in (?, ?, ?, ?, ....)`. On top of that, it doesn't bloat the server-side query cache with almost identical queries that only differ in the number of arguments passed to the `IN` clause.

So this works pretty well.

However, I have some cases where I would like to the same but with pairs of values. Conceptually, I'd like to do something like:

```
select * from MY_ENTITY where (TAG_NAME, TAG_VALUE) in (TABLE(?, ?))`
```

Where each of the parameters are SQL `ARRAY`s of identical length. But of course, this doesn't work with Oracle.

So far, the only way I've found to make that work is rather horrifying (though it seems to work)

```sql
select * 
from MY_ENTITY 
where (TAG_NAME, TAG_VALUE) IN (
    select TAG_NAME, TAG_VALUE
    from
        (select ROWNUM as IDX, column_value as TAG_NAME from TABLE(?)) A,
        (select ROWNUM as IDX, column_value as TAG_VALUE from TABLE(?)) B
    where
        A.IDX = B.IDX
    );
```

Is there any easier way to do that with Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the statement `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, the query will be faster.

In these statements, you only need to specify in the `WHERE` clause the condition to join the tables.

```
select * 
from MY_ENTITY my_ett
where EXISTS (
    select A.TAG_NAME, B.TAG_VALUE
    from
        (select ROWNUM as IDX, column_value as TAG_NAME from TABLE(?)) A,
        (select ROWNUM as IDX, column_value as TAG_VALUE from TABLE(?)) B
    where
        A.IDX = B.IDX AND A.TAG_NAME = my_ett.TAG_NAME AND B.TAG_VALUE = my_ett.TAG_VALUE
    );
```

Comment: It's an improvement, but not exactly the kind of improvement I was looking for. Postgres for example has a very handy `unnest` function that condenses the whole ugly subquery to a single function call. I was wondering if Oracle had something similar.

Comment: I have only 2 years of experience in Oracle. And I can’t help you. My problem was with IN statement and I solved it with EXISTS, but I don’t know that usage you are mentioning. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, it's entirely possible that Oracle doesn't have a simpler way at all. It is notoriously inconvenient for developers. It's supposedly better for administrators, but I have no idea if that's true or not.